# Sparql Variable depth search from a starting node

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to achieve the following thing :

Get all connected nodes with a variable depth (something i can speccify as a parameter?) between 1 and 5, from a specific node as a starting point.

Example : I want to find all of Jim's friends of friends of friends ( depth 2 )

So far i've been unsuccessfull and can only do depth 1 by adding additional properties like this :

```
select * where {

   ?Source foaf:name ?Name .
   ?Source foaf:member ?Target .
   ?Target foaf:name ?Name2 .
   ?Source2 foaf:member ?Target2 .
   filter(?Source = <MYIRI>)
}
```

Update 1:
I've managed to achieve something workable by adding paths:

```
select distinct * where {
   ?Source foaf:name ?SourceName .
   ?Source foaf:member/foaf:member ?Target .
   ?Target foaf:name ?TargetName .
   filter(?Source = <IRI>)
}
```

So this will search with depth 1, and if i want depth 2 i will have to do

```
?Source foaf:member/foaf:member/foaf:member ?Target .
```

Comment: not possible in SPARQL 1.1 - you have to do it on the client side, i.e. create the query string on request with the appropriate triple patterns.

Comment: There may exist triplestore-specific solution... Which triplestore do you use? You can try something like `foaf:member/foaf:member?/foaf:member?/foaf:member?/foaf:member?/foaf:member?`. Perhaps AKSW means that `{m,n}`-syntax is not a part of the SPARQL 1.1 specification.

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin Maybe, but as far as my understanding goes, this ( and my update 1) solution won't really work, as i don't get intermediate connections above depth 0. i only know that something from depth 2 is connected to the source, but not what links it goes trough, does that make sense?

Comment: @Aviatrix, `?` means "zero or one". "1" + "0 or 1" +  "0 or 1" +  "0 or 1" +  "0 or 1" +  "0 or 1"  is equal to "1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6" :-).

Comment: Yes, i understand that, but the results show that the source is connected to the target, but not the connections along the path. So i will get all connections, but everything will show as connected to the source and not between eachother

Comment: Then see AKSW's first comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the max depth is known (as it is in your case) you could use `UNION` block and select the nodes reachable at the requred distances up to the max depth.

Use a `FILTER` within each block of that big `UNION` so to enable its solutions. E.g. something along the following lines should do it, just alter the first `BIND` to the required depth or you may pass it as binding when evaluating your query:

```
select ?source ?target ?hops where { 
    bind(1 as ?depth) .
    values ?source {<urn:1>}
    { 
        filter (?depth > 0) .
        ?source <urn:p> ?target . bind (1 as ?hops) .
    } union {
        filter (?depth > 1) .
        ?source <urn:p>/<urn:p> ?target . 
        bind (2 as ?hops) .
    } union {
        filter (?depth > 2) .
        ?source <urn:p>/<urn:p>/<urn:p> ?target . 
        bind (3 as ?hops) .
    } union {
        filter (?depth > 3) .
        ?source <urn:p>/<urn:p>/<urn:p>/<urn:p> ?target . 
        bind (4 as ?hops) .
    } union {
        ?source <urn:p>/<urn:p>/<urn:p>/<urn:p>/<urn:p> ?target . 
        bind (5 as ?hops) .
    }
}
```